# Resposive mobile navigation css

Tags: html, jquery, css, navigation, responsive

Can anyone help me fix my responsive navigation. What CSS do I need to make the sub nav scroll down in mobile mode. Also the animation makes the nav hard to click on and when I resize the page the navigation does not return to its correct position. Help me please.

https://codepen.io/patriciaworth/pen/OJRBEbX

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="sub-nav.css">
    <!--Jquery-->
    <script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="nav-container">
    <nav>
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="hosts.php">Hosts</a></li>
                <li><a href="membership.php">Membership</a></li>
                <li><a href="affiliations.php">Affiliations</a></li>
                <!--dropdown-->
                <li class="dropdown"><span class="sub-link">Shop</span>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">Products</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">My Account</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Cart</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Checkout</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="mobile-toggle">&#9776;</div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="nav-underline"></div>
</div>
<!--mobile nav toggle-->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //mobile nav click event
        $(".mobile-toggle").click(function(){
            $(".menu").slideToggle();
        });
        $(".dropdown").click(function(){
            $(".dropdown ul").slideToggle();
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dosis:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700;800&display=swap");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Titillium+Web:ital,wght@0,200;0,300;0,400;0,600;0,700;0,900;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,600;1,700&display=swap");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Sansita+Swashed:wght@300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap");
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none; }

.container {
  min-width: 360px;
  max-width: 1080px; }

.nav-container {
  width: 100%;
  background: #183153;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #183153, #2e5d9e, #2e5d9e, #6190d1);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10; }

.nav-underline {
  height: 4px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ffcb05, #ffcb05, #ffe066);
  animation-name: underlineToRight;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 11; }

@keyframes underlineToRight {
  from {
    width: 0; }
  to {
    width: 100%; } }
nav ul {
  font-family: "Dosis", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 25px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative; }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    nav ul {
      position: absolute;
      top: 74px;
      left: 0px;
      background: #2e5d9e;
      width: 100%;
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      display: none; } }
nav ul > li {
  display: inline-block; }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    nav ul > li {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center; } }
nav ul > li > ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 160px;
  background: #2e5d9e; }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    nav ul > li > ul {
      width: 100%;
      position: relative; } }
nav ul > li > ul > li {
  width: 100%; }
nav ul > li:hover ul {
  display: block; }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    nav ul > li:hover ul {
      display: none;
      width: 100%; } }
nav ul li a,
nav .sub-link {
  color: #ffffff;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer; }
  nav ul li a:hover,
  nav .sub-link:hover {
    background: #c6c6cc;
    color: #183153; }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 1366px) {
    nav ul li a,
    nav .sub-link {
      font-size: 14px; } }
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  nav ul > li {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.3); } }
nav .mobile-toggle {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 25px 0px;
  text-align: right;
  right: 20px;
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative; }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    nav .mobile-toggle {
      display: block;
      width: 100%; } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok after much deliberation I have found an answer. See here:

https://codepen.io/patriciaworth/pen/rNMQyVx

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="sub-nav.css">
    <!--Jquery-->
    <script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="nav-container">
    <nav>
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Hosts</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Membership</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Affiliations</a></li>
                <!--dropdown-->
                <li class="dropdown"><span class="sub-link">Shop</span>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">Products</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">My Account</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Cart</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Checkout</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="mobile-toggle">&#9776;</div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="nav-underline"></div>
</div>
<!--mobile nav toggle-->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //mobile nav click event
        $(".mobile-toggle").click(function(){
            $(".menu").slideToggle();
        });
        
        $(".dropdown").click(function(){
            $(".dropdown ul").slideToggle();
        });

        //window resize event
        $(window).resize(function(){
            var w = $(window).width();
            if(w > 1024 && $('.menu').is(':hidden'))
            {  
                $('.menu').removeAttr('style');  
            }  
        });  
        
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

SCSS

```
//breakpoints
$mega: 1920px;
$xlarge: 1680px;
$large: 1366px;
$med: 1024px;
$tiny: 768px;

//colors
$blue: #183153;
$blue2: #2e5d9e;
$blue3: #6190d1;
$light-blue: #336699;
$yellow: #ffcb05;
$yellow2: #ffe066;
$light-grey: #90909c;
$med-grey: #434343;
$dark-grey: #363636;
$white: #ffffff;

//fonts
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dosis:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700;800&display=swap');
$heading-font: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Titillium+Web:ital,wght@0,200;0,300;0,400;0,600;0,700;0,900;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,600;1,700&display=swap');
$page-font: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Sansita+Swashed:wght@300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');
$cursive: 'Sansita Swashed', cursive;

*
{
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.container
{
    min-width: 360px;
    max-width: 1080px;
}
.nav-container
{
    width: 100%;
    background: $blue;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, $blue, $blue2, $blue2, $blue3);
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}
//animation
.nav-underline
{
    height: 4px;
    //background: $yellow;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, $yellow, $yellow, $yellow2);
    animation-name: underlineToRight;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 11;
}
@keyframes underlineToRight
{
    from 
    {
        width: 0;
    }
    to 
    {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
nav
{
    //top ul
    .menu
    {
        font-family: $heading-font;
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 25px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
        position: relative;

        @media only screen and (max-width: $med)
        {
            position: absolute;
            top: 74px;
            left: 0px;
            background: $blue2;
            width: 100%;
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
               box-sizing: border-box;
            display: none;
        }
    }
    //nav items
    ul>li
    {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        @media only screen and (max-width: $med)
        {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
        }  
    }
    //dropdown
    ul>li>ul
    {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        width: 160px;
        background: #333;
        @media only screen and (max-width: $med) 
        {
            width: 100%;
            position: relative;
        }
    }
    //dropdown items
    ul>li>ul>li
    {
        width: 100%;
    }

    //top nav links
    a,
    .sub-link
    {
        display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 15px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        transition: 0.3s;
        cursor: pointer;

        @media only screen and (max-width: $large) 
        {
            font-size: 14px;
        }
    }
    //top nav link color
    .menu>li>a,
    .sub-link
    {
        color: $white;
        &:hover 
        {
            background: lighten($light-grey, 20%);
            color: $blue;
        }
    }
    //show arrow icon so user knows to click for dropdown
    .sub-link:after
    {
        content:" \25BC";
    }
    //dropdown link color
    .dropdown>ul>li>a
    {
        color: #fff;
        &:hover 
        {
            background: #ccc;
            color: $blue2;
        }
    }
    //mobile item display
    ul>li
    {
        @media only screen and (max-width: $med) 
        {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.3);
        }
    }
    //mobile icon
    .mobile-toggle
    {
        color: #fff;
        padding: 25px 0px;
        text-align: right;
        right: 20px;
        display: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        position: relative;

        @media only screen and (max-width: $med)
        {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
        }
    }
    
}
```

CSS

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dosis:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700;800&display=swap");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Titillium+Web:ital,wght@0,200;0,300;0,400;0,600;0,700;0,900;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,600;1,700&display=swap");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Sansita+Swashed:wght@300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap");
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none; }

.container {
  min-width: 360px;
  max-width: 1080px; }

.nav-container {
  width: 100%;
  background: #183153;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #183153, #2e5d9e, #2e5d9e, #6190d1);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10; }

.nav-underline {
  height: 4px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ffcb05, #ffcb05, #ffe066);
  animation-name: underlineToRight;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 11; }

@keyframes underlineToRight {
  from {
    width: 0; }
  to {
    width: 100%; } }
nav .menu {
  font-family: "Dosis", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 25px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative; }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    nav .menu {
      position: absolute;
      top: 74px;
      left: 0px;
      background: #2e5d9e;
      width: 100%;
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      display: none; } }
nav ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative; }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    nav ul > li {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center; } }
nav ul > li > ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 160px;
  background: #333; }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    nav ul > li > ul {
      width: 100%;
      position: relative; } }
nav ul > li > ul > li {
  width: 100%; }
nav a,
nav .sub-link {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer; }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 1366px) {
    nav a,
    nav .sub-link {
      font-size: 14px; } }
nav .menu > li > a,
nav .sub-link {
  color: #ffffff; }
  nav .menu > li > a:hover,
  nav .sub-link:hover {
    background: #c6c6cc;
    color: #183153; }
nav .sub-link:after {
  content: " \25BC"; }
nav .dropdown > ul > li > a {
  color: #fff; }
  nav .dropdown > ul > li > a:hover {
    background: #ccc;
    color: #2e5d9e; }
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  nav ul > li {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.3); } }
nav .mobile-toggle {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 25px 0px;
  text-align: right;
  right: 20px;
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative; }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    nav .mobile-toggle {
      display: block;
      width: 100%; } }
```